# Переход от SSR к CSR в NextJS

Tags: nextjs, redux-thunk

Cовсем недавно начал изучать NextJS.  Есть пара вопросов из раздела «практический опыт» и «хорошая практика».
**Итак:**
Можно ли указать Next’у, что конкретный компонент я хочу отдать для рендеринга на стороне клиента.
Если да, то как и при каких условиях использовать этот подход целесообразно?

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл прикрепить текст ошибок, которые возникают и код, при котором это происходит. 
Так же наверное имело смысл разбить этот вопрос на 2, но тут уже субъективное мнение

Comment: В общем, русская версия этого сайта, как выяснилось - мёртвая. Тут только придирки к вопросу и оформлению могут написать. По делу - 0. Закройте тему пожалуйста